# How to tell if a function is continuous in an interval

Tags: analysis

I'm currently creating a program to plot simple graphs in 2D. In order to draw those properly I have to know if a function graph is continuous between 2 points on the graph.

Assuming the graph for f(x)=tan(x) and two points on the graph P1(1,tan(1)) and P2(2,tan(2)). Is there an algorithmic way to tell if the graph is continuous for 1 <= x <= 2?

thanks

Comment: The famous $\epsilon \text{,} \delta$ method is the algorithm you seek.  http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=epsilon+delta

Comment: In floating point arithmetic... it's hard to tell. There is the example $f(x)=3x^2+\frac{\ln((\pi-x)^2)}{\pi^4}+1$. The best you can do is that during the plotting process, ensure that either the slope or distance between two consecutive points on the graph is not "too big".

Comment: You might also want to look into implementing adaptive subdivision to ensure that glaring discontinuities are easily caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use interval arithmetic to compute reliable plots. See for instance this paper: Jeff Tupper, [Reliable Two-Dimensional Graphing Methods for Mathematical Formulae with Two Free Variables](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf), SIGGRAPH 2001. The excellent [GrafEq](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/) software uses this technique.

Comment: Interval arithmetic is the "guaranteed correct" way of catching discontinuities in a plot; it's not (very) fast, but if the functions to be plotted are simple enough, it's very reliable.