# Algorithm to find roots of a scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, algorithms, solution-verification, roots

Let $f : D\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth (e.g. Lipschitz continuous). I'm trying to develop a numerical algorithm which gives a large number of roots of $f$ with **a minimum amount of function evaluations**. This can also be understood as getting the contour 'line' $$\{x \in D \,|\, f(x)=0\}.$$

My attempt: Fix $\epsilon,\delta>0$ and perform the following recursion to get a sequence of roots $r_i$:

1. Sample a point $p_0 \in D$ uniformly at random such that $|f(p_0)| > \epsilon$.
2. Sample a point $p_1 \in D$ uniformly at random such that $|f(p_1)| > \epsilon$.
3. If $f(p_0)$ and $f(p_1)$ have opposite signs apply '[secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method)' to get root $r_1$ with $|f(r_1)| < \epsilon$. Otherwise go to 2.
4. Calculate the tangent to $r_1$ and get $p_2$ on it a distance $\delta$ appart from $r_1$.
5. Do 3. with $p_2$ and either $p_0$ or $p_1$ (such that they have opposite signs) to get $r_2$.
6. Do 4. with $r_2$ and so on to trace the contour.
7. Restart at 1. to find other unconnected parts of the contour.

[image]

How could this algorithm be improved? Or do you know a better method? Is it better than 'marching squares'? Would it even work to get complicated contours like that:

[image]

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15182/589.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll have a deeper look. Thanks!

Comment: Marching squares gives precise contours of an approximated field (bilinear approximation) with fixed number ($N^2$) of function evaluations. And it gives some guarantee that all features will be resolved provided that they are larger than the grid spacing. You may try to estimate the number of evaluations of your algorithm. I believe that 1 and 2 will waste too much evaluations. Calculating tangents requires differentiation, that gives even more evaluations. And beware of "angles" on contours, where tracing along tangent may lead you out of the contour.

Comment: @uranix You're right. Finding all components of the contour is indeed the more challenging part. A randomized method is not really guaranteed to find all of them. The problem with MS is that it wastes points in areas far away from zeros.

Comment: 3Blue1Brown has a [beautiful visualization](https://youtu.be/b7FxPsqfkOY) of an ingenious root finding method for two variable equations.

Comment: @K.defaoite Nice find. But it seems limited to the case where $f(x)=\vec{0}$ (vector 0).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to improve the 'marching squares' algorithm. Consider only Lipschitz continuous functions.
W.l.o.g assume that $D$ is a square, $f \geq 0$ and $\forall x,y\in D : |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \|x-y\|$.

**Algorithm:**
Fix $\epsilon >0$ and cover $D$ by a regular $m \times m$ grid of square cells, where $x_{i,j}$ is the center of cell $(i,j)$. Let $A$ be a $m \times m$ zero matrix.

1. set $x=x_{1,1}$
2. set $A$ to $1$ at the index of $x$ and

   if $f(x) \geq \epsilon$ then $\forall (k,l) : ||x-x_{k,l}|| < f(x)$ set $A_{k,l}=1$

   else mark $x$ as a root
3. go serpentine-like through $A$ to find the next zero entry $x$ and go back to 2.

**Example:** Let $D=[0,8]\times[-4,4]$ and
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} \left|\sin(x)\sin(x-y) - \sin(y) \sin(x+y) -\frac{1}{2}\right|, \ (x,y)\in D.$$

Plot of $f$ with contour (red).

[image]

The algorithm uses 90.2% less evaluations than 'marching squares' to achieve the same accuracy.

[image]

Combining this algorithm and contour tracing should reduce the evaluations even further.